# How to programmatically set the pose of a 3d humanoid model?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am an experience programmer, but new to working with 3d models.

I have some data regarding the orientation (pitch,roll,yaw) of various bones (arms,legs,head,spine etc) .

I would like to take a 3d humanoid model (maybe one that looks like a skeleton), and programmatically pose it by setting the orientation of each bone.

Can someone point me in the right direction? This seems like something very simple and basic for someone who knows how.

I am using both iOS and Android

Edit: I just want to be able to see what the model looks like when it is posed. This is not a video game or animated picture or anything. It’s just for motion capture.

Answer (score 0):

i think it depends on your 3d engine. for example in jpct_ae it look like

```
Object3D cube = loadModel("",  (float) 1);
            cube.build();
            world.addObject(cube);

            cube.setOrigin(new SimpleVector(0, 0, 10));
```

where 0,0,10 is x,y,z. in opengl it similar but with one turn to left.
or try set origin to center.
other way is get screen width and height and then set to center
example

```
public int getScreenWidth() {
        int columnWidth;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

        final Point point = new Point();
        try {
            display.getSize(point);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError ignore) {
            point.x = screenWidth;
            point.y = screenHeight;
        }
        columnWidth = point.x;
        return columnWidth;
    }
```

but first way is best, because is simplest in renderer and you can set any pposition you want.

Comment: Well in your example you set the position of the object, but have made no mention about posing individual limbs of a humanoid model. Can you point me in the right direction, or suggest some cross platform engine where it is easy to do so? (I need an example)

Comment: i use blender. paste object in position you want and, choose first and second (in object mode) and Ctrl+J to combine them to one object. after this export obj, 3ds or other.

Comment: I’m targeting mobile, so is there an engine you suggest for mobile?

Comment: Yes. For first you need create 3d model (or download and change). You can create/change it in blender, 3dMax, Maya, etc. Also in blender you can set motion/position for every bone (look blender model rigging/animation). And when model is ready export it in fbx or dae. After this all you need use any 3d engine to render it in your app like open_gl, jpct_ae, rajawali, jbones or other. in android app i use jpct_ae and rajawali.

Comment: Now i work on this. i create model, rigging and animation in blender. And problem is export it in md5anim/md5mesh. Need blender addon for 2.8 version on python 3.7

Comment: You can’t use blender in mobile. Is there some alternative you suggest?

Comment: blender is for creating on pc. "And when model is ready export it in fbx or dae. After this all you need use any 3d engine to render it in your app like open_gl, jpct_ae, rajawali, jbones or other. in android app i use jpct_ae and rajawali"

Comment: Ok.but how will you programmatically set the bones to a specific pose, just by specifying angles?

Comment: for example. i will create animated model in blender, convert it to awd and render it in rajawali. in animation a will create specific poses (fast position changes without cicles, repeating). but it on android. Maybe you need Unity3d. is crossplatform. try read unitys forum

Comment: "just by specifying angles". if angles set user it will be more difficult and now i not have ideas for this

Comment: and little idea. maybe this help. for example in jpct (in other it similar i think). load human and load hand. set hand as child (hand.setParent(human) and set position human.setPosition(new Simplevecto(0,0,10), hand.setPosition(new Simplevector(-2,0,7) for left hand.). Change hands pose (bend elbow) hand.rotateY(usersAngle). But before you need change hands center point/origin (it for rotation around elbow but not fingers or hands center).